# Debian sheevaplug internet not working

Tags: linux, networking

I have a sheevaplug with debian 5.0..internet was always working fine until today. I have a bunch of pcs connected via wireless to my router and internet works fine. From today though my debian won't connect to the internet and i have no idea why... when I run `ping google.com` I get this:

```
ping google.com
PING google.com (173.194.35.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
443 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 442006ms
```

It stays like this forever and I am unable to wget anything. Here is some info that might be useful :
Content of `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# Used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8). See the interfaces(5) manpage or
# /usr/share/doc/ifupdown/examples for more information.
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Output of `ifconfig`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:ad:4e:01:40:78
          inet addr:192.168.2.12  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f2ad:4eff:fe01:4078/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2200 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2926 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:229615 (224.2 KiB)  TX bytes:466378 (455.4 KiB)
          Interrupt:11

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Content of `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 192.168.2.1
```

Here is the output of `netstat -rn`:

```
debian:~# netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
```

Output of `arp -na`:

```
debian:~# arp -na
? (192.168.2.1) at 00:1a:2a:27:c0:68 [ether] on eth0
```

Output of `route`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
default         .               0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

I tried everything : static IP, restarting network connection, restarting router, no luck... Any ideas what might be wrong?

---

**Edit**: Here's the output of `route`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
default         .               0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

---

**Edit**: Here's the output of `netstat -rn`:

```
debian:~# netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
```

and `arp -na`:

```
debian:~# arp -na
? (192.168.2.1) at 00:1a:2a:27:c0:68 [ether] on eth0
```

Comment: It might be useful to look at a traceroute.

Comment: Can you ping local machines?, whats the output of "route"

Comment: Rather than just `route`, show the output of `netstat -rn` and `arp -na`.

Comment: What's the output of `traceroute -n google.com`?